# Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to setup my new project which is using JAVA16 and gradle based springboot project. But, when i am trying run it locally i have following error:

```
> Task :bootRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I had verified java version also. However I tried to run from both cmd, powershell and from the terminal in Intellij.

Can some one suggest me the tip to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have java path set correctly? if yes, run java --version in command line and see if it points to correct version?

Also check in IntelliJ that if you have correct project SDK set. Project SDK and Project Language level should point to same version.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to run with `--stacktrace --debug` so you will get more information about the failure.